# How to implement two-factor authentication using microsoft authenticator

Tags: .net, identityserver4

I want to integrate with microsoft authenticator in identity server 4 application but i don't know how or which steps,

I made many search but without any result

Comment: Search for "time-based one-time password".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 0):

I recommend referring to our documentation, which contains comprehensive implementation guidelines:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-7.0.  We're also happy to provide support if you have any problems reading the documentation or need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i didn't understand this documentation :(